# Xamarin.Forms Add and Share Item CrashApp

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, argumentnullexception

Good morning to all, I've looked in several places I researched and did not found a solution that worked for my problems.
I'm new to C #, XAML and Xamarin, I am doing an application that creates lists with products on a screen, the screen with products is been populated via Json WebApi. Until there everthing looks fine, but since i tried to add 'ADD' and 'Share' functionalities it is loading the main page and crashes on navigating to listsPage. 
I need to get a product from the product Page and add it to another view where my lists are. I created a ContextActions with 'Share' and 'AddToList' but i don't know how to get that product and 'Add' it to my lists. Same problem with 'Share' when i get the MenuItem and try to pass it to a Task in my ProductViewModel i get a NullReferenceException, but the object is not null.
I appreciate if someone could help me with this issues.
I know the post has got quite long but i wanted to give every possible info.

Here is my Lists Page:

```
<ListView x:Name="listaView" ItemSelected="listSelected" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout Padding="20,0,20,0"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

            <Image Source="check.png"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   IsVisible="{Binding Done}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
       </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

and my listDetail:

```
    <Label Text="Name" />
    <Entry x:Name="nameEntry" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <Label Text="Description" />
    <Entry x:Name="descriptionEntry" Text="{Binding Description}" />
    <Label Text="Typ" />
    <controls:BindablePicker x:TypeArguments="enums:Typ" SelectedItem="{Binding Typ}" />
    <Label Text="Done" />
    <Switch x:Name="doneEntry" IsToggled="{Binding Done}" />
    <Label Text="Products:" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                <Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='R${0:C2}'}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button Text="Save" Clicked="salveClicked" />
    <Button Text="Delete" Clicked="deleteClicked" />
    <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="cancelClicked" />
    <Button Text="Speak" Clicked="speakClicked" />

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ListDetails CODE BEHIND:

```
public ProductListDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);

                   }

        void saveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lista = (Lists)BindingContext;
            App.Database.SaveList(lista);
            this.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        void deleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lista = (Lists)BindingContext;
            App.Database.DeleteList(lista.ListaID);
            this.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        void cancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lista = (Lists)BindingContext;
            this.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        void speakClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lists = (Lists)BindingContext;
            DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().Speak(lists.Name+ " " + lists.Descrip);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is in my model but have no idea what it is

Product Model:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int ProductID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(id)));
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(name)));
            }
        }

        private double price;
        public double Price{
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(price)));
            }
        }

        private string dtFab;
        public string DtFab
        {
            get { return dtFab; }
            set
            {
                dtFab= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(dtFab)));
            }
        }

        private string dtValid;
        public string DtValid        {
            get { return dtValid; }
            set
            {
                dtValid= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(dtValid)));
            }
        }

        private string amount;
        public string Amount{
            get { return quantidade; }
            set
            {
                amount= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(amount)));
            }
        }

        private string descrip;
        public string Descrip{
            get { return descrip; }
            set
            {
                descrip= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(descrip)));
            }
        }

        private string image;
        public string Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set
            {
                image= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(image)));
            }
        }

        private ICollection<ListProduct> listProduct;
        public ICollection<ListProduct> ListProduct{
            get { return listProduct; }
            set
            {
                listProduct= value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(listProduct)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

ListsModel:

```
public class Lists
    {

        public Lista()
        {
        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ListID get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Descrip { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }
        public Typ Typ { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<ListsProduct> ListsProducts{ get; set; }

}
public class ListsProduct
{
        public int ListsProductID{ get; set; }
        public int ListID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public virtual Lists Lists { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ListProductModel:

SearchProductPage:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchBarText}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnPesquisar" Text="Search" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
              <MenuItem Text="Share" Clicked="ShareProduct" />
              <MenuItem Text="Add To" Clicked="AddProduct" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                <Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='R${0:C2}'}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

SearchPage CODE BEHIND:

```
 public partial class SearchPage: ContentPage
    {
        ProductsViewModel viewModel;
        public TelaPesquisaView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.ProductsViewModel();
        }


        public async void AddProduct(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var al = ((MenuItem)sender);
            await viewModel.AddToList(al.BindingContext as Product);
            var produtoLista = new ListsPage();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(produtoLista);
        }

        public async void ShareProduct(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var al = ((MenuItem)sender);
            if (al != null) { 
            await viewModel.Share(al.BindingContext as Produto);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the ProductViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string searchBarText = string.Empty;
        public string SearchBarText {
            get { return searchBarText ; }
            set
            {
                if (searchBarText != value)
                {
                    searchBarText = value ?? string.Empty;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(searchBarText )));

                    if (SearchCommand.CanExecute(null))
                    {
                        SearchCommand.Execute(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // filtrar somente os 5 primeiros

        #region Command SearchCommand
        private Xamarin.Forms.Command searchCommand;
        public ICommand SearchCommand{
            get
            {
                searchCommand= searchCommand?? new Xamarin.Forms.Command(DoSearchCommand, ExecuteCommand);
                return searchCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                searchCommand= (Xamarin.Forms.Command)value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(searchCommand)));
            }
        }
        private void DoSearchCommand()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Products)));
        }
        private bool ExecuteCommand()
        {
            return true;
        }
        #endregion
        private ObservableCollection<Models.Produto> products; 
        public ObservableCollection<Models.Produto> Products             {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Models.Product> searchProducts = new ObservableCollection<Models.Product>();

                if (products != null)
                {

                    List<Models.Product> prod = (from p in products
                                                 where p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchBarText.ToLower())select p).Take(3).ToList<Models.Product>();

                    if (prod != null && prod.Any())
                    {
                        searchedProducts = new ObservableCollection<Models.Product>(prod);
                    }
                }
                return searchedProducts ;
            }  
            set
            {
                products = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Products)));
            }
        } 

        public ProductsViewModel()
        {
            SearchCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
            {
                var products = await ApiProducts.Api.GetAsync();
                Products = new ObservableCollection<Models.Product>(products );
            });


        }

        public async Task AddToList(ListsProduct prod)
        {

            Lists list = new Lists();
            list.ListsProduct.Add(prod);
            App.Database.SaveList(list);


        }
        public async Task Share(Models.Product prod)
        {
            var title = prod.NomeProduto;
            var message = prod.ToString();


            // Share message and an optional title.
            await CrossShare.Current.Share(message, title );


        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just share your solution somewhere? dropbox?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for not posting it earlier.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7xcouu90vo69cms/AABGXgGlrSxw22KJfTMRQArWa?dl=0

Comment: So, I was able to build it and run on Android. I see 2 tabs page but it's not in English. What should I press to see the problem? I was able to click on "AGORA Nao" then "+" sign and add product to "MINHAS LISTAS"

Comment: I'm sorry my Project is in portuguese and i didn't have the time to translate it
You should click on "Pesquisa(Search)" Tab if you click on "Pesquisar(Search)" Button it i'll load some products and on long pressing a product it ill load a menu with 2 options. What i'm trying to achive is when you press "Adicionar à(Add To)" get the pressed item and add it to a list in "Minhas Listas(My lists)".

Comment: There is one more thing for some reason android can't access the data, if you use uwp it will load the products data just fine.

Comment: I see httpclient points to localhost. Is it going to be used in your scenario?

Comment: It ill, but just for testing purposes, i couldn't find a way to make it run on android using localhost.Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You have to use IP address for your PC where service is running if they are on the same network. Also you cannot host your service in Express in this case, use local IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the starting point for you. For the rest you can use the same pattern passing your new product in constructors or just implement setters in your view models.

1. Define binding to get a new product

   ```
   <MenuItem Text="Adicionar à" Clicked="AdicionaProduto" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
   ```
2. Then pass it to your ListasView constructor as parameter

   ```
   public async void AdicionaProduto(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var al = ((MenuItem)sender);
           var produtoLista = new ListasView(al.CommandParameter as Produto);
           await Navigation.PushAsync(produtoLista);
       }
   ```
3. To be able to do that you need to change a constructor

   ```
   public ListasView(Produto newProduto = null)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.ListasViewModel();

       if (newProduto != null)
       {
           //do something
           int x = 0;
       }
   ```

You can take that newProduto and store it in your DB or pass further to other models or views via constructor or some setters.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. i'll try it later and check result, but again thanks for taking some time to help me.